# Liberty LDAP always uses full DN to search for group membership

Tags: ldap, open-liberty

OpenLiberty 23.0.0.9 connected to OpenLDAP 2.5.16. Using a custom filter in

Users are identified by **uid** - eg, user Roy McRoy has uid of 'roy'.

Groups are of objectClass **posixGroup**. Members are identifed by the '**uid**' value in the **MemberUid** attribute. For example, Group 'Controlled' has an attribute value 'MemberUid:roy' to show roy is a member of the 'Controlled' group.

[How it looks in Apache Directory Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBE5b.png)

The groupMemberIdMap is "posixGroup:memberUid"

BUT - and here's the problem! - when Liberty searches Groups to find the MemberUid values, it ALWAYS searches using the user's full DN= , not just the short **uid** value.

I want to configure the LDAP Repository in Liberty so that Liberty will search groups for:

```
memberUid=roy
```

... and not ...

```
memberUid=cn=roy,ou=i2users,dc=i2support,dc=lan
```

But so far nothing seems to work.  What am I doing wrong? How can I search group memberships for just 'roy'?

Turning on LDAP logging via  element in server.xml shows Liberty using the full DN value for roy, as the search term:

```
[2023-12-24T14:55:17.909+1100] 0000002f LdapConnectio >  search Entry  
         dc=foosupport,dc=lan
         (&(|(objectClass=posixGroup)(objectClass=posixgroup))(memberUid=cn=roy,ou=foousers,dc=foosupport,dc=lan))
         null
   javax.naming.directory.SearchControls@25af6f52
         null
[2023-12-24T14:55:17.909+1100] 0000002f ContextManage >  getDirContext Entry
```

Which correctly finds no groups - because the real value of MemberUid is just 'roy', not 'cn=roy,ou=foousers,dc=foosupport,dc=lan'

Here is my repository:

```
<ldapRegistry id="OpenLDAPreg"
              ldapType="Custom"
              realm="ldapRealm"
              host="LDAP01.foobar.lan"
              port="389"
              baseDN="dc=foobar,dc=lan"
              bindDN="cn=Manager,dc=foobar,dc=lan"
              bindPassword="P@ssword01!">
    <customFilters userIdMap="*:uid"
                   groupIdMap="*:cn"
                   userFilter="(&amp;(uid=%v)(objectclass=person))"
                   groupFilter="(&amp;(cn=%v)(|(objectclass=posixGroup)))"
                   groupMemberIdMap="posixGroup:memberUid">
    </customFilters>
</ldapRegistry>
```

Here is the LDIF information:

1. User 'Roy McRoy"

```
[root@LDAP01 ~]# ldapsearch -xLLL -D "cn=Manager,dc=foosupport,dc=lan" -W "(uid=roy)"
Enter LDAP Password: 
dn: cn=roy,ou=foousers,dc=foosupport,dc=lan
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
uid: roy
sn: Analyst
displayName: Roy McRoy
mail: fred@foosupport.lan
userPassword:: UEBzc3dvcmQwMSE=
cn: roy
```

2. Group "Controlled"

```
[root@LDAP01 ~]# ldapsearch -xLL -D "cn=Manager,dc=foosupport,dc=lan" -W "(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=Controlled))"
Enter LDAP Password: 
version: 1

dn: cn=Controlled,ou=fooGroups,dc=foosupport,dc=lan
gidNumber: 259
cn: Controlled
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
memberUid: bill
memberUid: fred
memberUid: roy
```

3. My own ldap search to see if roy is a member of group Controlled works fine:

```
[root@LDAP01 ~]# ldapsearch -xLL -D "cn=Manager,dc=foosupport,dc=lan" -W "(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberuid=roy))"
Enter LDAP Password: 
version: 1

dn: cn=Analyst,ou=fooGroups,dc=foosupport,dc=lan
gidNumber: 257
cn: Analyst
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
memberUid: roy
memberUid: fred
memberUid: bill

dn: cn=Controlled,ou=fooGroups,dc=foosupport,dc=lan
gidNumber: 259
cn: Controlled
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
memberUid: bill
memberUid: fred
memberUid: roy

[root@LDAP01 ~]#
```

How can I make Liberty search for Group memberships, like my own ldapsearch commend searches?

There is no scope to change the LDAP database, it belongs to a Federal govt organization with thousands of users, hundreds of offices, and many other LDAP-consuming applications. I have to make Liberty work with the LDAP server, not vice versa.

Very grateful for any assistance!

Comment: Hi Andrew and welcome to StackOverflow! Membership often works with the `dn` because of uniqueness. Maybe your configuration breaks some assumptions made by the software you use. Is there another attribute in the group with the `dn` value, or can you duplicate attributes to have both `uid` and `dn`?

Comment: Many thanks, ixe013! Your response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't change anythjng on the LDAP server. It belongs to the customer. We're just one of many applications at the site.

There's no existing attribute in the schema with the dn. The memberUid attribute, which in their schema shows membership, takes a simple uid value. So somehow we have to search for groups where memberUid = uid.

They have many other applications working off this LDAP server, so it seems like it should be possible.

Very grateful for any ideas!

Comment: Check if userID is correctly mapped in your app. For example put somewhere `request.getRemoteUser();` to check if uid in your app is short or full dn. You could try to change `userIdMap="*:cn"` as it looks like in your case `cn==uid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we opened a PMR with IBM so the WebSphere SMEs could look at it. Their answer: it can't be done in Liberty. Liberty will ALWAYS search for group membership using full DN, you can't force it to use a truncated uid value.

Arguably the underlying problem is ambiguity in RFC 2307. It defines memberUid in the schema, but doesn't say what data should go in the memberUid value. One implementation could use plain uid, another implementation use the full DN. They're both "RFC-compliant" - but incompatible.

So we're giving up on LDAP and looking at client certificate authentication instead.